# Why is nodejs throwing error named: TypeError: Cannot read property 'x_auth' of undefined?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I am trying to authorize the user. So I am writing a middleware as follows:

```
const userModel = require('../models/User');

let auth = (req, res, next)=>{
    let token = req.cookies.x_auth;
    userModel.findByToken(token, (err, user)=>{
        if(err) throw err;
        if(!user) return res.json({
            isAuth: false,
            err:true
        })
        req.token = token;
        req.user = user;
        next();
    })
}

module.exports = auth;
```

This is my router:

```
router.get("/auth",auth, (req,res)=>{
    res.status(200).json({
        _id : req.id,
        isAuth: true,
        email: req.user.email,
        name: req.user.name,
        lastname: req.user.lastname,
        role: req.user.role
    })
})
```

But I am getting an error named: **TypeError: Cannot read property 'x_auth' of undefined** while I send request to that route from insomnia. Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use[image] req.headers.authorization   instead of  req.cookies.x_auth which i was explained in picture.

Comment: I haven't installed cookie-parsar. That was the problem.